# Images or tables are not exactly centered

Tags: horizontal-alignment

Hello dear TexExchange community,

I'm having a weird problem which can be basically summarized with following image:

[image]

I'm including images like following:

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering 
\caption{Benutzeransicht der ersten Umfragerunde}
\vspace{0.4em}
\includegraphics[width=15cm]{Bilder/03_Methodik/ansicht.png}
\label{benutzeransicht}
\vspace{0.8em}
\begin{flushleft}
\footnotesize 
Quelle: Eigene Darstellung (Phonic.ai).
\end{flushleft}
\end{figure}
```

As I'm pretty inexperienced with LaTex, I can't tell what I#m doing wrong. Can someone help please? :)

Comment: Put the `\label` next to `\caption` and leave blank lines around `\vspace`.

Comment: Oh wow, that was some quick help! Thank you very much, it worked! :)

Comment: Why do you set `[width=15cm]` instead of `[width=\textwidth]`?

Answer (score 1):

You have a space between `\includegraphics[...]{...}` and `\label`, because the endline gets converted to a space. Also, `\label` refers to the `\caption`, not to the picture.

It's also better to set `\vspace` between paragraphs. Adapt them after trying the code below.

```
\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering 

\caption{Benutzeransicht der ersten Umfragerunde}
\label{benutzeransicht}

\vspace{0.4em}

\includegraphics[width=15cm]{Bilder/03_Methodik/ansicht.png}

\vspace{0.8em}

\raggedright\footnotesize 
Quelle: Eigene Darstellung (Phonic.ai).

\end{figure}
```

Why `htp`? Because you want that LaTeX finds a way to place the figure. Why `\raggedright`? Because `flushleft` adds vertical space around it.

Answer (score 0):

The non-centering issue vanishes automatically if you replace `[width=15cm]` with `[width=\textwidth]`. Doing so will also let you omit the `\centering` directive and the `flushleft` environment. Oh, and do make sure to execute the `\label` directive after, not before, the `\caption` directive.

[image]

```
\documentclass[demo]{article} % remove 'demo' opton in real doc.
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht]
\caption{Benutzeransicht der ersten Umfragerunde} \label{benutzeransicht}

\medskip
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Bilder/03_Methodik/ansicht.png}

\medskip
\footnotesize 
Quelle: Eigene Darstellung (Phonic.ai).
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

For writing note about image source I would use `\usepackage{copyrightbox}` package:

```
\documentclass[demo]{article} % remove 'demo' option in real doc.
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{copyrightbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht]
\caption{Benutzeransicht der ersten Umfragerunde} \label{benutzeransicht}
\copyrightbox[b]{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Bilder/03_Methodik/ansicht.png}}
                {Quelle: Eigene Darstellung (Phonic.ai).}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```